# Formality of surfaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, rational-homotopy-theory, derham-cohomology

The de Rham dg algebra $\Omega(F)$
 of a closed orientable surface $F$
 is formal
 (that is, weakly equivalent to its cohomology algebra).
 This is a special case of the fact of formality of Kähler manifolds.

Can one prove formality of $\Omega(F)$ without using complex analysis?
 Say, by explicitly constructing its Sullivan model
 (which has to be infinitely generated, I guess).

Comment: What do you mean by "Sullivan model" for a space which isn't simply connected?

Comment: @Qiaochu Every space has a Sullivan minimal model (namely, a minimal cdga with a quasi-isomorphism to the cdga of polynomial de Rham forms); if the space is nilpotent (for example simply connected spaces), then the usual theorems hold, for example the statement that the number of generators in a certain degree is equal to the dimension of the rational homotopy group in that degree. Similarly, formality can be defined for any space. It’s worth noting that there is no nilpotence/simply-connected assumption in the DGMS paper proving that Kahler manifolds are formal.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  By a Sullivan model I mean a weak equivalence from
 a free commutative dg algebra
 whose generators are labelled by positive integers called ranks
 and which is equipped with a differential that sends each generator
 to the subalgebra generated by those of smaller ranks.
 (But I do not insist on constructing a Sullivan model.)

Comment: Perhaps you can argue as follows: show that a torus is formal (since a product of formal spaces is formal, and a circle is formal), and then argue that the connect sum of formal manifolds is formal. For the connect sum part, there is Theorem 3.13 here https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/tanre.pdf. They restrict to simply connected manifolds, but maybe the argument goes through without the nilpotence/simply connectedness assumption.

Comment: @Aleksandar Milivojevic Let us consider the connected sum of two 2-tori $M$ and $N$
 and follow the proof of that Theorem 3.13.
 The added generators $x_i$ have degree $\ge1$
 (it is written there that they have degree $\ge2$,
 but this is not so in our case because of $H^1$).
 Then it is not clear why
 the arrow
 $$
 (H^*M\oplus_{\mathbb Q}H^*N)\otimes\Lambda(x,x_i)
 \to
 (H^*M\oplus_{\mathbb Q}H^*N)/(\omega_M-\omega_N)
 $$
 (which sends $x$ and $x_i$ to zero)
 respects the differential.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Semen:

In Felix, Halperin, Thomas: Rational Homotopy Theory II, World Scientific 2015, it is shown (see Ch. 8, section 5) that orientable surfaces are even better than formal. They are intrinsically formal. That is, any commutative cochain algebra with the same cohomology $H_g$ as a surface (of genus $g$ here) has the same minimal model as that of $(H_g,d=0)$. They don't use Deligne-Griffiths-Morgan-Sullivan, but they do base their arguments on earlier material, so be prepared for a bit of a slog. As one of the previous commentors said, any path connected space has a minimal model, but if the fundamental group and/or its action on higher homotopy groups is bad (i.e. non-nilpotent say), then the construction is via a transfinite induction which makes the resulting model very hard to understand and work with. So the bulk of RHT II is determining a class of spaces called Sullivan spaces where techniques akin to those in the authors' book RHT (Springer Grad. texts) can be used. The definition of Sullivan space builds in the exact amount of control needed for the fundamental group and its action to be amenable to rational homotopy algebraic analysis. One unsatisfying part of the definition however is that the rational cohomology of the universal cover must be finite-dimensional in each degree and so simple examples are not Sullivan spaces.